# How would we solve $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x+\cos x}$ by using L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Problem here is at one point after differentiating both numerator and denominator, I get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x+\cos x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{1-\sin x} $$

after that what should I do,I get sin(infinity) and same for cosine, got stuck here what to do next?

Comment: Divide everything by $x$ and use that 'bounded times zero is zero', that is that $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\to0$ when $x\to\infty$

Comment: @Poppy 'bounded times infinity',you mean?

Comment: Nope, bounded times zero: $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\sin{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: "$\frac{1}{\infty}=0$"

Comment: oooh....yes yes :) Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, since the assumptions of De l'Hospital's theorem are not satisfied. This is something you should understand: some limits **cannot** be solved by differentiation.

Do you need a solution? Here it is:
$$
\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\cos x} = \frac{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1+\frac{\cos x}{x}} \to 1
$$
as $x \to +\infty$, because $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ remain bounded.

Comment: then how to solve this?

Comment: I've added a solution.

Comment: how did you solve sinx/x ?

Comment: @Rishi $\sin(x)$ is bounded, so $\sin(x)/x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: $$\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \leq \frac{1}{x} \to 0.$$

Comment: @Siminore OK,Nice Solution.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your expression can be rewritten as $$\frac{x}{x+\cos (x)}-\frac{\sin (x)}{x+\cos (x)}$$ which is clearly convergent

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $x > 1$ then

$$\frac{x-1}{x+1}   \leq \frac{x-\sin x}{x+\cos x}  \leq \frac{x+1}{x-1}$$